# C program for creating folders based on file extensions and copying files with the extensions into them

Tags: c, pointers, path, file-manipulation

I am trying to create a c program that reads the extensions of the files in its current working directory.
The program then creates folders that correspond to the extensions of the files. It then copies each file 
from its cwd into the corresponding folder. 
e.g:

> hello.txt into created .txt folder

The code successfully creates folders for all the file extensions in the current directory, but crashes when it begins to copy.

Here is the whole code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *input, *output;   // Two files, input and output
    char ch;    // ch is used to assign characters from input file which will then be copied into the output file
    char *exe = ".exe";
    struct dirent *de;

    DIR *dr = opendir("."); // Open directory for reading
    printf("%s", dr->dd_name);

    // If directory doesn't exist, quit
    if(dr == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open current directory.");
        return 0;
    }

    // Loop first to create a directory corresponding to all
    // extensions present in the current directory
    while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        char *filename = de->d_name;    // Get the filename
        char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.'); // Get the extension

        if(!(!ext || ext == filename)){ // Compare extension
            int check = mkdir(ext);

            if(!check)//Check if the directory was created
                printf("Directory created successfully.\n");
            else {
                printf("Unable to create directory.\n");
            }

        }
    }

    // Close the directory so as to reset the pointer ready for the next read.
    closedir(dr);

    dr = opendir(".");

    // Loop  reading each file and checking which
    // directory it corresponds to.

    while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        char *filename = de->d_name;    // Get the filename
        char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.'); // Get the extension
        if(!(!ext || ext == filename)){ // Check for a valid extension
            DIR *file_ext_dir = opendir(ext); // Open the dir that corresponds to the extension of the file.
            char *dir_name = file_ext_dir->dd_name; //Get the dir name of the opened directory

            if(file_ext_dir && (strcmp(dir_name, "..") != 0)&& (strcmp(ext, exe) !=0) ) { //ignore .exe and the cwd
                printf("Successfully opened: %s dir\n", file_ext_dir->dd_name);
                char *output_path = strcat(dir_name, filename);
                printf("Ready to copy files from %s to:  %s\n", filename, output_path);

                output = fopen(output_path, "a+");  // Open output.txt for appending, if doesn't exist, create it.
                input = fopen(filename, "r");   // Open the input file ()'filename') for reading


                while(1) {  // Loop through the input file
                    ch = fgetc(input);  // Get the current character
                    if(ch == EOF) break;    // Stop if EOF is found
                    putc(ch, output);   // Put current character from the input file into output.txt
                }

                fclose(input);  // Close input file
                fclose(output); // Close output file
                closedir(file_ext_dir);
            } else if(ENOENT == errno){ //Check if there is no such directory and handle the error
                printf("Dir does not exist.");
            }else {
                continue; //Skip that file if for some reason the directory cannot be opened.
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dr);   // Close directory
    printf("Created directories and copied all files to that correspond to them.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this for some practical purpose? If so, a simple script can do it in easier and more portable way

Comment: This sounds that something that would a lot easier to do in a scripting language.

Comment: Review errant construction of path with `strcat(dir_name, filename);`

Comment: `// If directory doesn't exist, quit
    if(dr == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open current directory.");
        return 0;
    }` is a little confusing.  I think you mean `/* if directory doesn't exist, fail */ if(dr == NULL) {perror("."); return EXIT_FAILURE;}`